# Drupal page.tpl.php template for dynamic URL's

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I read about the basic [path/template naming](http://drupal.org/node/190815#page-suggestion) in Drupal, but I couldn't figure out how to handle dynamic URLs.

Say, I have a page on : *www.example.com/company/companyname/news* - and company name is dynamic.  Is there a way that I can create a template page for this, such as page-company-*-news.tpl.php? (which, of course, is an illegal file name).  This field, "company name" could also contain hyphens ("-").

I am running Drupal 6, and paths are created with Pathauto.

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: I replaced the URL according to [RFC 2606](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add custom template suggestions in a preprocess function. See [Working with template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440) for details.

Comment: Thank you!  I also found [page node template](http://drupal.org/project/node_page) which I'm trying out now, just to keep it modular.